# Regex to extract path from file

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regexp or string split/replace that will return the filepath with the following tests

```
let filepath_1 = "./path/to/file.js";     // ./path/to/
let filepath_2 = "./path/to/file.min.js"; // ./path/to/
let filepath_3 = "./path/to/";            // ./path/to/
let filepath_4 = "./path/to";             // ./path/to
let filepath_5 = "/path/to";              // /path/to
let filepath_6 = "path/to";               // path/to
```

The slashes in the final results don't really matter, as long as the file is gone from the results and that it doesn't think that `to` is a file name..

My best effort so far is using `file.replace(/[^\/]*$/, "")` but it will remove the `to` in `/path/to`. I need some logic about the "." character

Comment: Folder names can also have a dot (.) in the name.

Comment: Filenames don't have to have dots in them.

Comment: My folders will not have dots, and my files will. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to *replace* what you do not need based on the examples above (that is, *if you just need to remove the file names at the end of the path*):

```
.replace(/[^\/]+\.\w+$/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O3fDHS/2). The regex will match one or more chars other than
a `/` (with `[^\/]+`), then a `.` (with `\.`) and then any one or more word chars (`\w+`) at the end of the string (`$`).

You can use the following to *extract* what you need:

```
/^(?:\.*\/)?[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oj3SP7/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\.*\/)?` - an optional sequence of zero or more `.` chars followed with
  a `/`
- `[^\/]+` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `[^\/]+` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\/?` - an optional `/` char

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
let filepath_1 = "./path/to/file.js";     // ./path/to/
let filepath_2 = "./path/to/file.min.js"; // ./path/to/
let filepath_3 = "./path/to/";            // ./path/to/
let filepath_4 = "./path/to";             // ./path/to
let filepath_5 = "/path/to";              // /path/to
let filepath_6 = "path/to";               // path/to 
const arr = [filepath_1, filepath_2, filepath_3, filepath_4, filepath_5, filepath_6];
// Replacing
const reg = /[^\/]+\.\w+$/;
arr.forEach( x => console.log(x, "=>", x.replace(reg, '')) )
// Matching
const regex = /^(?:\.*\/)?[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/?/g;
arr.forEach( x => console.log(x, "=>", x.match(regex)?.[0]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex may not produce the most readable solution in this case since there is an `if/then` implicitly. What about a simple `split`?

```js
p = ["./path/to/file.js", "./path/to/file.min.js", "./path/to/", "./path/to", "/path/to", "path/to"]
output = p.map(s => {

  // Begin
  a = s.split("/")
  if (a[a.length - 1].includes(".")) {
    a.pop()
    return a.join("/") + "/"
  }
  return a.join("/")
  // End

})

console.log("output", output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

https://regex101.com/r/XPalNK/2

Replace this pattern with an empty string.

```
(!?[\w-]+\..*)
```

Comment: Well that was clever indeed. +1

Comment: Why do you try to match an exclamation mark? There are none in OP input.

Comment: @RyszardCzech exclamation mark + question mark means an optional input